# OnMessage event-handler differs from Documentation - why?

Tags: delphi, eventhandler, delphi-10.4-sydney

The [Delphi documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnMessage.html) defines `TApplication.OnMessage Event` as `TMessageEvent` which is defined as `procedure (var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean) of object;`

However, when in Delphi 10.4 I double-click in the `OnMessage` field of `ApplicationEvents1` in the Object Inspector to insert the `OnMessage` event-handler, then I get this code:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  
end;
```

Do you note the difference between `TMsg` and `tagMSG`? Is this a BUG?

Comment: `TMsg = tagMSG`, they are the same type. The object inspector relies on RTTI, which does not differentiate between declared aliases vs the types they are aliasing.  In this case, the declaration of `TMessageEvent` really does use the `TMsg` alias, but the actual type it refers to is `tagMSG`, which is what RTTI sees.

Comment: They are exactly the same. If you ctrl-click `tagMSG` in the snippet above, you are taken to Windows.pas where the `tagMSG` record type is defined. On the line below, you'll find `TMsg = tagMSG`. So they are exactly the same.

Comment: So why are there 2 different denominations?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @user1580348: `tagMSG` is there to match [the Win API declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg). `TMsg` is there because it sounds more Pascal-ish.

Comment: OK. I understand.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I always hated that Delphi does that.  It just makes things more confusing, especially at a time when cross-platform wasn't a thing yet.  And it doesn't carry through RTTI, and thus through HPP generation for C++ users, like me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau don't blame Delphi for their attempt to align things and get them more in order since 1996. I, in contrast, was irritated that identifiers starting with lowercase letters (like `tagMSG`) can also by types.

Answer (score 3):

In the past (around 1996) Delphi used to be shipped with the WIN32.HLP, at that time with a gargantuan filesize of ~20 MiB and **the** reference for looking things up. But all explanations, definitions and examples were written in C++, which added another level of burden to Pascal developers. If nowadays things irritate you you may have been lost 20+ years ago - mixing different names for the same types was already a thing back then.

[(Archived) http://laurencejackson.com/win32/](https://web.archive.org/web/20220922051031/http://laurencejackson.com/win32/) mentions CHM versions available with screenshot (see the "Download" button on the left side); it's still a valuable file when you're offline for a long time:

- [10.9 MiB from 2016-01-03 by Laurence Jackson](https://web.archive.org/web/20220914153850/http://laurencejackson.com/win32/Win32.chm)
- [6.68 MiB from 2014-10-02 by Mike Lobanovsky](https://web.archive.org/web/20210416210144/https://www.oxygenbasic.org/o2zips/Win32.chm)
- [23.66 MiB from 1998-06-18 by Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20071012030630/http://www.powerbasic.com/files/pub/mstools/Win32.zip) (HLP file, packed in a SETUP.EXE)

Comment: Nice work! What I would find very useful: An EXTENSIVE collection of practical WinAPI  EXAMPLES for modern Delphi! Do you know if such a book exists? I would pay a fair price for such a book!

Comment: I don't use books for programming anymore since 2002 and offline documentations are virtually inexistent, especially MSDN. My strategy is mirroring individual websites like https://theroadtodelphi.com/category/winapi-2/ for having many examples at once for later reading.

Comment: The link is not working anymore :-(

Comment: @MichaelHutter Welcome to the internet which also has a few useful crawlers - I've updated/extended my post, linking to copies on https://archive.org/ - you can always search any given URI to see if snapshots from the past are available there.